# Show weight on the content screen

Tags: views, nodes

Is is possible to show the weight select box on admin/content, rather than having to go into the node to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

[Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight) Module Provides it : [Read Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/307797)

> On the Content administration page (Administration » Content), there will be a "Weight"
>   column containing a selector box to set the weight of any node with a content type that has been weight enabled.

And Here is a [Comparison of Node/Entity Ordering Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/398508)

- To enable Weight for a content type, go to Administration » Structure » Content
  types and select the content type you want to enable Weight for. Select the Weight
  vertical tab, choose your desired settings, and click the Save button.

[image]

- Now in `admin/content` you could see weight column

Comment: it's drupla 7 and there is no weight field even though it is enabled. I have cleaned the cache.

Comment: Check my updated answer..